# « Je vous envoie » ou « Je vous envois » ?

Tags: orthographe, conjugaison

Écrit-on :

- « Je vous envoie »

ou

- « Je vous envois »

Je pense que les deux sont valables mais j'aimerais savoir pourquoi.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais rencontré *Je vous envois* et le considèrerais comme une erreur. Est-ce bien une forme utilisée quelque part ?

Comment: Je crois qu'alji est un peu confus parce que *envoyer* a la conjugaison de *voir* au futur et conditionnel.

Comment: il s'agit bien d'une erreur de ma part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Envoyer* est un verbe du 1<sup>er</sup> groupe, il se conjugue en conséquence :

> J'envoie, tu envoies, il envoie, etc.

Il ne faut pas confondre avec les terminaisons du verbe *voir*. Quant à *envois*, ça ne peut être que le pluriel du nom *envoi*.